# How to call a method in a python xml?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have a method python that returns a value X, It is this value that I want to get an xml file whitch representing the tree view in odoo. How will I call this method in the xml file to display this value?

Answer (score 0):

XML is declarative language, therefore you cannot "call" any functions in XML file. You can insert result of your python function manually in specific place of XML document on the generation XML phase (if you build it on-fly).

If you have static file with XML document on your disk, you can insert a magic placeholder in XML and replace it by python function result after read the XML-file content.

test.xml:

```
<root>
  <things>
    <thing>
      <title>[%company_name%] Some title</title>
    </thing>
  </things>
</root>
```

xml_reader.py

```
my_company_name = 'Example LTD.'
with open('test.xml', 'r') as fp:
    content = fp.read()
    content = content.replace('%company_name%', my_company_name)
    print(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

look my methode python 
`def affiche():
 return result[0].name`

I want to display this result in view xml odoo described in the following code:

```
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="document_tree_view">
     <field name="name">document.tree.view</field>
     <field name="model">document_binov.document_binov</field>
     <field name="type">tree</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <tree string="Documents">
           <field name="titre"/>
           <field name="description"/>
           <field name="type" />
      </tree>
     </field>
    </record>
```